STM32 how to use the same timer to generate PWM (at varying frequencies) and a fixed 1ms interrupt
I’m using an STM32L452RET (no RTOS) and would like to use the same timer (timer 2) for two purposes:

Drive a sounder with PWM at 4 kHz, ideally with the flexibility to change frequencies above and below a 1 ms period for more complex sounds


Generate a 1 ms interrupt to handle other tasks.

What would be the best way to do that?
I tried setting the PWM to 1ms for the interrupt to check other tasks and drive the buzzer pin directly (instead of the PWM peripheral) but then it would not create frequencies higher than 500Hz for the buzzer.
Thank you. 

The best way to achieve that would be to use two timers, or one timer for the PWM and use the ARM's sysTick interrupt for the 1ms tick.

Thank you but that is rather obvious... My question is about using a single timer.

Maybe [edit] your question to explain why you can't use the obvious solution, and absolutely must only use a single timer. Feels like you're making life difficult for yourself for no real reason. Your STM32 has 8 timers.

"frequencies above and below a 1 ms period" is somewhat vague, and conflicts with your earlier mention of 4KHz.  Specify the desired frequency range in Hz.  Do you really need "PWM" or just a frequency?  You say nothing about duty-cycle.  Do you require the output to be driven by the OC output if the timer, or do you not care?  What other time critical work will the processor be performing?

The thing is SYSTICK is useful for nothing other than generating a periodic interrupt (it has no input capture or output compare/PWM capability).  So by avoiding using it for its intended purpose leaves it redundant, for no good reason - there is a reason why it is a "rather obvious" suggestion - it is exactly for this purpose.  You have to justify your self-imposed constraints if you don't want others to suggest the "obvious" better and more appropriate solution.

Thank you all :)
the reason for not using the other timers is that they are all already used to control other devices, motors etc.
At the end I modified the setup and code to go with the first suggestion from @pmacfarlane
I am new to this forum, how do I select that answer as the correct one?
Thank you

The ARM Cortex-M4 CPU inside your STM32 MCU has a Systick timer which is specifically designed for generating periodic interrupts at a fixed frequency, or for other timing-related purposes. This would be perfect for your 1ms tick.
Then you could use the other timer for your PWM signal, and vary its frequency, duty cycle, or whatever, as you see fit, without disturbing the 1ms tick.

Thank you for selecting the answer for me. For the future, how do I do that myself? I am new to this forum and did not see any options to do so. Thank you.

My original "answer" was just a comment on your question and not an answer, and so could not be accepted. After you commented that my comment was a solution, I wrote an answer containing that information. You can accept this answer by clicking the tick icon beside it. And you could upvote it, by clicking the up arrow. This is not really the way this site normally works; normally someone would just post an answer directly. But we did not know why you were so constrained to use a single timer, hence the questions.
